# Set specific orientation only for first launch in AppDelegate.m iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, orientation, screen-orientation

I'm using this library for my react native project:

[react-native-orientation-locker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker)

What I'm trying to achieve is to lock to orientation to portrait on all screens except one. And this library works fine except in a situation where user closes the app in landscape mode and then tries to open it while still in the landscape mode. For a very brief moment the app opens in landscape and then rotates to portrait. But I don't want to see that and instead, I want to open the app in portrait mode when it launches.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

   /*if (the app has just been launched) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }*/

   // else, use the library to manage and set orientation
   return [Orientation getOrientation];
}
```

I don't know how to check the first launch and what to put in the above if statement

Answer (score 0):

native-orientations is a very good library to detect and set the orientation of your device. As you can see the  document there is property to unlock all the orientations. ie; orientation.unlockAllOrientations()

you can use this in componentWillUnmount/ get the current state of app and call that function if it goes to background or so it will force to unlock all the orientations and after that you can set the orientation to potrait in component did mount of main file like app.js.

> componentDidMount() {
>
> ```
>     Orientation.lockToPortrait(); // <----- This will reset stuff before the first unlock
> }
>
> componentWillUnmount() {
>     Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
>     Orientation.lockToPortrait();
> }
> ```

hope this helps you....

Comment: Thanks for the reply @saikiran. That's what I'm already doing. But it doesn't work. When I launch the app it starts with landscape and then rotates to portrait mode. The problem is, closing the app doesn't call `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: ok then when you open the app before rendering the views update the orientation by using constructor or componentWillmount

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for some entry in UserDefaults, if it's not contains object you provided, then it first launch. After that you can just put this object into UserDefaults

e.g.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SOME_YOUR_KEY"] == nil) {
    // First faunch Code
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SOME_YOUR_KEY"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else {
    // Not first launch
}
```

Comment: as per the suggestion that you have given this works on first launch of app after installation. but this doesnt work on closing the app and opening again. Correct me if im wrong. Thanks!!